# Import pg erroring out in Python3.9

Tags: python

whenever I use `import pg` in my code I get following error

```
>>> import pg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pg/__init__.py", line 3
    async,
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried it using pyCharm and terminal directly as well. I am using Python3.9 , `import sys; print(sys.version)` output

```
3.9.1 (default, Dec 29 2020, 08:52:17)
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.28)]
```

My objective is to use connect to redshift. However I am able to use pg8000 but what does this error mean? As per documentation online `async` was added after python 3.3 and since I am using 3.9 it should get imported without error

Comment: The problem is that async is a keyword in python 3.7+ maybe

Comment: Yes i am aware but i am using 3.9 in console as well pyCharm

Comment: @GarvitArora Can you check on which version of PyGreSQL you have installed? Is it the latest one?

Comment: i don't see PyGreSQL when i run `pip list installed`. However i did install after your comment using `pip install PyGreSQL` it installed 5.2.2 and i tried `import pg` still the same error

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because you have a 'pg' package installed that is conflicting with the pg module. You may have installed

```
pip install pg
```

instead of

```
pip install PyGreSQL
```

library. This async keyword issue is from the former.
Assuming you dont need the other pg module, delete the pg directory altogether (in your case from /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pg) , install the pygresql using the correct pip command if not done already, and try again. you should not get these issues.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! To remove the pg directory, you can just `pip uninstall pg`

Comment: Thanks so much for this! This saved me lots of time